# DoubleAnimation - Rotating image

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

In Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight I would be able to take an image in my XAML page and fully rotate it once with the following Storyboard.

```
<Storyboard x:Name="rotate_searching_image">
    <DoubleAnimation AutoReverse="False"                             
        Duration="0:0:10"
        From="0"
        RepeatBehavior="1x"
        Storyboard.TargetName="searching_image"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
        To="360" />
</Storyboard>
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in my new Windows Phone 8.1 runtime app but I get an error saying the the property `Angle` cannot be found. If I change the `TargetProperty` to `Opacity` and update `From` and `To` to appropriate values, everything works.

I've looked through `UIElement` and can't find any property or method that lets me set the angle.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither `UIElement` nor `FrameworkElement` have the `Angle` property. You need to apply the animation to the `Angle` property of a `RotateTransform`.

First, you need to create a transformation object:

```
<Image x:Name="searching_image">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

Then change the `TargetProperty` to this:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="rotate_searching_image">
    <DoubleAnimation AutoReverse="False"                             
        Duration="0:0:10"
        From="0"
        RepeatBehavior="1x"
        Storyboard.TargetName="searching_image"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
        To="360" />
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: Thank you. It rotates but it looks like it rotates around the top left corner. Can it rotate around the center of the image? This is what I see. http://imgur.com/8pLnOgs

Comment: Nevermind, setting ```RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"``` on the Image made it work. Thanks!